# How to run a exe on cmd with multiple parameters programmatically on C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I need to execute a exe with parameters as shown above screen shot via C# code.

it looks like

```
C:\Users\singha33\Desktop\1111>TaskFileSigner.exe 
TaskFile="C:\Users\singha33\Desktop\1111\ApplyingSecurity.eTask.xml"   
ProcessFile="C:\Users\singha33\Desktop\1111\Firefox_Setup_Stub_46.0.1.exe" 
GenKey="Y" Singner="Ak"
```

I tried

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
proc.FileName = "C:\\Users\\singha33\\Desktop\\1111\\TaskFileSigner.exe";
string temp = "C:\\Users\\singha33\\Desktop\\1111\\ApplyingSecurity.eTask.xml";
string argument1 = "TaskFile=" + '"' + temp + '"';
string argument2 = "ProcessFile =" + '"' + "C:\\Users\\singha33\\Desktop\\1111\\Firefox_Setup_Stub_46.0.1.exe" + '"';
string argument3 = "GenKey =" + '"' + "Y" + '"';
string argument4 = "Signer =" + '"' + "Aksh" + '"';
proc.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", argument1, argument2, argument3, argument4);
//proc.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
```

But it is not working. I am very new to this kind of work and has no clue how to proceed further. May be i am not passing the argument properly or anything else.

Any help would be great.

I have searched similar kind of question on stack and found some helpful topics but it did not work. I think the argument is not properly formatted as it should be, but I have no idea how to format it properly.

One observation: I am getting exception

> "The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment variables."

when I debug and wait at the process start function " System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);". And when I do not wait and just press F5 it does not give any exception but the operation does not get successful either.

[image]

Comment: did you try setting `UseShellExecute` to false?

Comment: What error did you get? Did you print `proc.Arguments` and did it look right?

Comment: put a breakpoint after this line and check in the QuickWatch what the params look like make sure you have the proper spaces etc.. 
`proc.Arguments = String.Format`

Comment: Try setting the `WorkingDirectory` property:  `proc.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\singha33\Desktop\1111";`

Comment: I think the problem may be in how you are building your arguments. Try to remove that weird `+ '"' +` things ,for example: `string argument1 = "TaskFile=" + temp;
            string argument2 = "ProcessFile = C:\\Users\\singha33\\Desktop\\1111\\Firefox_Setup_Stub_46.0.1.exe";
            string argument3 = "GenKey =Y";
            string argument4 = "Signer = Aksh";`

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour can be reproduced.

When **inspecting** the `ProcessStartInfo` variable (your `proc` variable) **in the watch window** by opening it to see all properties then this Exception occurs. When closing it in the watch window so that all properties are hidden, the error is not thrown!

It is possible to watch the `proc.Arguments` and probably some others too.

I think that one of the getters internally changes something so it leads to this error.

My german exception message is "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Für das Process-Objekt muss die UseShellExecute-Eigenschaft auf "false" festgelegt sein, um Umgebungsvariablen zu verwenden.'"